# How can I make the line beneath my heading the same width as the text?

Tags: html, css

How can I make sure the line beneath my header is the same length as the text itself?

This is my HTML:

```
<h2>Hello world!</h2>
```

This is my CSS:

```
h2:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #f77f00;
  color: #f77f00;
}
```

What I have tried:

- Setting width of pseudo element to 100%
- width: inherit on pseudo element

CodePen example:
https://codepen.io/johnnybossboy/pen/zjGdVr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` on your `h2`

```
h2{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just set it as `inline-block` and get rid of the pseudo element entirely.

```
h2{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #f77f00;
}

// Remove pseudo element CSS
```